# Cannot cross-reference figure after using \captionof by using package xr-hyper

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, siunitx

I'm using `xr-hyper` package, because it can create hyperlinks to the external documents that are cross-referenced. I am using 'xr-hyper' package, beacuse I would like to produce multi-volume book which can collect my notes from different engineering projects.

I slashed the problem to a skeleton that consists of only two files.

- grain0050a.tex
- grain0050b.tex

I'm include figure with \captionof command and reference \label{fig:048} (see MNWE bellow) in file *grain0050a.tex*. Cross-reference is used in file grain0050b.tex. But it doesn't work. I come to the conclusion that, there is interference with package `siunitx`. It seems to me that code (T_1 = \SI{300}{\kelvin}) is used as a relative path (also grain0050a.aux file is included below). Unfortunately, I don't see anything strange there. I have no idea where to dig next.

[image]

**Figure 1:** compilation of the file grain0050b.tex. Note - grain0050a.tex have to be compiled first to create aux file.

**MWE: grain0050a.tex** (compiled without error)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xr-hyper} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\externaldocument[B-]{grain0050b}[grain0050b.pdf]% <- full or relative path 

\begin{document}
    This is a test for math.
    \begin{equation}
        E=mc^2 \label{eq:1}
    \end{equation}
    This is a second test for math.
    \begin{equation}
        r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \label{eq:2}
    \end{equation}
    In document B Eq.~~(\ref{B-eq:x}) 

  { \centering
    \captionsetup{type=figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{Maxwell's velocity distribution \(T_1 = \SI{300}{\kelvin}\).
    \label{fig:048}}
  \par}
\end{document}
```

I also try @UlrikeFischer hack `\protect` for fragile commands, but without success.

```
  { \centering
    \captionsetup{type=figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{Maxwell's velocity distribution \(T_1 = \protect\SI{300}{\kelvin}\).
    \label{fig:048}}
  \par}
```

Now I can see that AUX file is modified and key word \protect is shown there.

```
\newlabel{fig:048}{{1}{1}{Maxwell's velocity distribution \(T_1 = \protect \SI {300}{\kelvin }\). \relax }{figure.caption.1}{}}
```

But when I try to recompile grain0050b.tex (ofcourse grain0050a.tex was recompiled first) the pdflatex complains:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ... \(T_1 = \protect \SI {300}{\kelvin
                                                  }\). \relax
l.5 ...naldocument[A-]{grain0050a}[grain0050a.pdf]
                                                  % <- full or relative path
?
```

---

**MNWE: grain0050b.tex** (can't be compiled - see error log screenshot - figure 1)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\externaldocument[A-]{grain0050a}[grain0050a.pdf]% <- full or relative path

\begin{document}
As was shown in Eq.~(\ref{A-eq:1}) is it
  ... or in Eq.~(\ref{A-eq:2}) is ...
  \begin{equation}
    \mathrm{e}^{i\pi}-1=0 \label{eq:x}
  \end{equation}

  Maxwell's velocity distribution is shown in \ref{A-fig:048}
\end{document}
```

**Compilation scheme**

1. pdflatex grain0050a.tex
2. pdflatex grain0050b.tex
3. pdflatex grain0050a.tex

---

Aux file content of the grain0050.tex is:

```
\relax 
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\providecommand\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\AtBeginDocument}
\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\global\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
\gdef\contentsline#1#2#3#4{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\global\let\oldnewlabel\newlabel
\gdef\newlabel#1#2{\newlabelxx{#1}#2}
\gdef\newlabelxx#1#2#3#4#5#6{\oldnewlabel{#1}{{#2}{#3}}}
\AtEndDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\let\contentsline\oldcontentsline
\let\newlabel\oldnewlabel
\fi}
\fi}
\global\let\hyper@last\relax 
\gdef\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument#1{#1}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToFields[1]{}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToCoFields[2]{}
\newlabel{eq:1}{{1}{1}{}{equation.0.1}{}}
\newlabel{eq:2}{{2}{1}{}{equation.0.2}{}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Maxwell's velocity distribution \(T_1 = \SI {300}{\kelvin }\). \relax }}{1}{figure.caption.1}\protected@file@percent }
\providecommand*\caption@xref[2]{\@setref\relax\@undefined{#1}}
\newlabel{fig:048}{{1}{1}{Maxwell's velocity distribution \(T_1 = \SI {300}{\kelvin }\). \relax }{figure.caption.1}{}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}{}}
    \gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

Comment: You can use `\captionof{figure}{Maxwell's velocity distribution \(T_1 = \protect\SI{300}{\protect\kelvin}\)`. I'm not sure if there is a better solution, nameref is a bit of a problem here.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I try it, but it doesn't help. By using "\protect", nothing is changed in aux file.

Comment: I tried and it worked, but you have naturally to recompile the a-file.

Comment: It is strange. 1. I also did the Miktex update. The packages siuintx, mathtools, biblatex-ieee and latexindent were updated. 2. I did the deletion of all generated files. 3. pdflatex grain0050a.tex. 4. Check the aux file: "\newlabel{fig:048}{{1}{1}{Maxwell's velocity distribution \(T_1 = \protect \SI {300}{\kelvin }\). \relax }{figure.caption.1}{}}". It seems to be correct now. 5. pdflatex grain0050b.tex. 6. compilation error: "! Undefined control sequence... \(T_1 = \protect \SI {300}{\kelvin ...  <- full or rel"

Comment: I tried now on miktex too and worked. Show the log-file, then I can compare with mine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for your time Ulrike. I tried to prepare github commit: https://github.com/Jafanovic/Latex_Issue01. I can proceed the compilation when stroke the enter key after the compilator stops with error discribed above. Maybe your compiler uses different setting like nonstop mode.

Comment: you added only one \protect, but I used two, \kelvin needs protection too.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Ulrike Fischer's comment, the protection should looks like following:

```
\captionof{figure}{Maxwell's velocity distribution \(T_1 = \protect\SI{300}{\protect\kelvin}\)
```

It must be protected twice.