# siunitx version v3.0.2 with xr-hyper

Tags: hyperref, siunitx, xr

I am typeset the multivolume book. Simplest form looks like:

main file for volume one (**vol01.tex**)

```
  \documentclass{scrbook}
    \usepackage{xr-hyper}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \section{First section}\label{section}
  \begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Units \qty{10}{\m}}
    \label{fig:example}
  \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Tex file for volume two (**vol02.tex**):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
  \usepackage{xr-hyper} 
  \usepackage{hyperref}

  \externaldocument[B-]{vol01}[vol01.pdf]% 

\begin{document}
  Link to file \texttt{vol1} figure \ref{B-fig:example} in section \ref{B-section}. 
\end{document}
```

But the units used in caption leads to error:

```
...
/uniquecounter.sty")))
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> Units \qty
           {10}{\m }\relax
l.11 ...nt[B-]{vol01}[vol01.pdf]
```

For previous version of `siunitx` package the solution was to use `\protect\SI{10}{\protect\m}` according to the Ulrike Fischer solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/592495/cannot-cross-reference-figure-after-using-captionof-by-using-package-xr-hyper). Unfortunately it is no longer be valid.

Is there any other alterntive? For example usage of the `zref-xref` package.

Comment: no it not longer works. siunitx doesn't like the inner \protect.

Comment: Not related but you should change `vol01` in the second file with `vol1`...

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Is there any other alterntive? For example usage of the zref-xref package. How to work around this problem, or suggestion?

Comment: well it works if you load siunitx *and* move the \externaldocument[B-]{vol01}[vol01.pdf]%` after \begin{document}.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Ulrike Fischer's comment the solution is:

```
 \documentclass{scrbook}
  \usepackage{xr-hyper} 
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage{siunitx}     

  \begin{document}
    \externaldocument[B-]{vol01}[vol01.pdf]% 

    Link to file \texttt{vol1} figure \ref{B-fig:example} in section \ref{B-section}. 
  \end{document}
```